# Sublime Key "Build With" Binding

Tags: sublimetext3, key-bindings

I just started coding yesterday and I'm currently studying C#. I am using Sublime Text 3 as it is my favorite Code Editor. But I have a problem when compiling the C# file. When I am compiling, I always have to click the "Build With" and then Choose the "CSharp" and then click the "Build With" again and choose the "CSharp -Run" to see the changes in my codes. So what I want to know is how can i set a Key Bind for "CSharp" and "CSharp -Run"? Thank you in advance for someone who will answer my question.

Here's my Default Keymap:

```
{ "keys": ["f7"], "command": "build" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "build" },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "build", "args": {"select": true} },
{ "keys": ["ctrl+break"], "command": "cancel_build" }
```

And here's my the Default Keymap -user:

```
[
    { "keys": ["ctrl+r"], "command": "build", "args": {"select": true} },
]
```

And also this is my C# build-system:

```
{
    "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "del", "${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/}", "2>NUL", "&&", "csc", "/nologo", "/out:${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/}", "$file"],
    "file_regex": "^(...*?)[(]([0-9]*),([0-9]*)[)]",
    "variants": [
        { 
            "name": "Run", 
            "cmd": ["cmd", "/c", "start", "cmd", "/c", "${file/\\.cs/\\.exe/}"] 
        }
    ],
}
```

[Photo of my Sublime Text 3 with my said problem above](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YcIr5.png)
[Photo of my Key Bind for "Build With"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qCdM6.png)

Comment: Please post code as code, not image, as it makes it easy for answerers to reference.

Comment: It would be easier to help you if you also provided the contents of your `sublime-build` file (as text, not an image), but in short you want your key binding to pass an argument of `variant` and a value of something like `run` to make it do what you want.

Comment: I'm sorry. Here's my default keymap: `{ "keys": ["f7"], "command": "build" },
 { "keys": ["ctrl+b"], "command": "build" },
 { "keys": ["ctrl+shift+b"], "command": "build", "args": {"select": true} },
 { "keys": ["ctrl+break"], "command": "cancel_build" },` And then I changed the Ctrl+Shift+B to Ctrl+R.

Comment: @Xcoder I have updated my question. Please help.

Comment: @OdatNurd I have updated my question. Please help.

Comment: Is there any particular reason why you have the main build compile the code and the variant running it instead of having the variant compile and run in one action?

Answer (score 4):

The short version of the answer to your question is that you're not providing the correct argument to the `build` command, so what you've done is duplicate an existing key binding on another key; you want to pass the `variant` argument instead to tell Sublime directly to run the build with the variant you want to execute.

The longer version is that the `build` command takes two arguments, `select` and `variant`.

The `select` argument tells Sublime that before it runs the build, if there is more than one applicable build for the current file (for example there is more than one build system or there are variants that apply), it should ask you for the build first. This is the same as the <kbd>Ctrl+Shift+B</kbd> keyboard shortcut or the `Tools > Build With...` menu entry.

What you want instead is the `variant` argument; that tells Sublime that it should carry out the build using the last build system that was used, but it should explicitly use the `variant` that you provided.

For the case of your build system, your key binding would look like this:

```json
{
    "keys": ["ctrl+r"],
    "command": "build", "args": {
        "variant": "Run"
    },
},
```

The value of the `variant` argument has to exactly match the `name` key in the `variants` section of your build system (i.e. case is important). If you get it wrong, instead of building nothing will happen and you'll see a message appear in the status line like `No Build System with variant whatever`.

Note that this key binding blocks the default key binding for `Goto Symbol`, should you want to use that functionality while you're working. The command is still available in the menu at `View > Goto Symbol` however.